# Spring & Maven & JUnit - BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, junit

I meet a exception in test phase when I try to build my project.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.service.test.UserServiceTest':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field: public com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.service.UserService
com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.service.test.TestContext.userService;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.service.UserService]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Project consist with multiple modules:

```
AdviceExchange
    ├── domain
    ├── dao
    ├── service
    ├── web
```

I don't understand why this happen, all DAO classes mapped as `@Repository` on Service layer all classes mapped as `@Service`.

It looks like my **Application Context for DAO** layer:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"....>

    <import resource="classpath:/spring/queries.xml"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adviceexchange"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.domain"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">

        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Application Context for Testing**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"...>

    <import resource="classpath:/spring/dao-application-context.xml"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dozortsev.adviceexchange"/>

    <!--
        Define configuration for embedded database
        Build HSQL database for unit testing in-memory
    -->

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="embeddedDatabase" type="HSQL">

        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/test-ddl.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/test-dml.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>
```

And also my **test classes**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:/spring/test-application-context.xml")
public abstract class TestContext {

    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestContext.class);

    @Autowired public UserService userService;

    private static EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @BeforeClass public static void setUp() {
        log.info("creates an HSQL in-memory database");
        db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("embeddedDatabase").build();
    }

    @AfterClass public static void tearDown() {
        log.info("shutdown database");
        db.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**UserServiceTest** is the class that throws an exception during building project

```
public class UserServiceTest extends TestContext {

    @Test public void testFindByLogin() {

        final String login = "sed.dui.Fusce@torquentperconubia.net";

        Assert.assertNotNull(userService);
        User user = userService.findByLogin(login);

        Assert.assertNotNull(user);
    }

    @Test public void testCreate() {

        // prepare data for service
        User user = new User(
                "Mario", 25, null, "Germany, Dortmund", null, "gotze@gmail.com", "gotze_mario", 1
        );
        Assert.assertNull(user.getId());
        userService.create(user);
        Assert.assertNotNull(user.getId());
    }
}
```

Please help me with solve this issue. I am be grateful to all the advices!

Comment: what is the exception post the full details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder is wrong

```
https://github.com/dozortsev/AdviceExchange/tree/master/service/src/test/resource
```

the maven convention is "resources" - with s at the end, so the test application context is not at the classpath.

Because you have classpath*:/spring/test-app-context... with * the missing file is ignored and then it can't find any beans because the context is empty.

Just fix the folder name.

Comment: Thanks!! But now I have another exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

Comment: If it is what I got (@Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.domain.Answer.user) then it is a separate issue and you should start new question.

Comment: Btw. having the source code on github really helps and you should highlight it more in your next question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all. I very grateful for your attention.